# Combine isodate header and simple week-based timeline in a gantt chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I'm trying to create a time chart and found the `pgfgantt` package to be the most suitable choice.

Basically I need a timeline about **23 full weeks**, something like:

```
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{23}
\gantttitlelist{1,...,23}{1} \\
```

However I'd like to include a rough calender with a **start date and end date, spanning full 23 weeks.** For example:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
time slot format=little-endian,
time slot format/start date=01-03-2016]{01-03-2016}{09-08-2016}
```

I already found out, that it's probably impossible to combine these to schemes within one gantt chart, so I thought, why not use the header of the one gantt chart and the structure of the second one:

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
x unit=.08cm,
y unit title=.6cm,
y unit chart=.6cm,
time slot format=little-endian,
time slot format/start date=01-03-2016]{01-03-2016}{09-08-2016}
\ganttset{bar height=.6}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname}
\end{ganttchart}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid={*{6}{draw=none}, dotted},
x unit=.45cm,
]{1}{23}
\ganttset{bar height=.6}
\gantttitlelist{1,...,23}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4} \\
\ganttbar{Long Task 2}{5}{23} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But I have a hard time aligning them properly.

**How can I ensure that the width of the header block fits the width of the second plot?**

Especially when I change the task labels everything gets screwed up, when I set the widths manually. You can assume the equalitity of the number of weeks for both blocks.

Solutions combining everything in one chart are welcome as well.

---

**Edit:**
I found that one could solve the problem on the basis of days:

```
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{161}

\gantttitlecalendar*[time slot format=little-endian]{01-03-2016}{08-08-2016}{year,month=shortname} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,23}{7}
```

But it's a little annoying to think in days, if one just wants to include events on a weekly basis. However mabye this approach can be used anyhow.